# Train simple RNN from a map of T/F values and bitstring keys in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, dataset, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch-dataloader

I want to train rnn netwwork that will be able to identify the folowing:
I have a Language L that made of bitstrings (can be in lengh n>20) which every bitstring that in the language satisfy the pattern of the language (which is not rellevant for now).

I created a dataset which is like a map with bitstrings as keys and True/False as values:

```
001101000010010, False
111001001000000, False
111011101001100, False
011111000101101, False
10000110000110001100, True
011100100001010, False
....
```

I tried to create rnn network in pytorch:

```
class myDataset(T.utils.data.Dataset):

def __init__(self, src_file, m_rows=None):
    tmp_x = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                       usecols=[0], delimiter=",", skiprows=0, dtype=np.int64)

    tmp_y = np.genfromtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                       usecols=[1], delimiter=",", dtype=bool)

    tmp_y = tmp_y.reshape(-1, 1)  # 2-D required

    self.x_data = T.from_numpy(tmp_x).to(device)
    self.y_data = T.from_numpy(tmp_y).to(device)

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.x_data)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    preds = self.x_data[idx, :]  # or just [idx]
    val = self.y_data[idx, :]
    return (preds, val)  # tuple of two matrices
```

and train it:

```
    net.train()  # set mode
for epoch in range(0, max_epochs):
    T.manual_seed(1 + epoch)  # recovery reproducibility
    epoch_loss = 0  # for one full epoch

    for (batch_idx, batch) in enumerate(train_ldr):
        (X, Y) = batch  # (predictors, targets)
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # prepare gradients
        oupt = net(X)  # predicted prices
        loss_val = loss_func(oupt, Y)  # avg per item in batch
        epoch_loss += loss_val.item()  # accumulate avgs
        loss_val.backward()  # compute gradients
        optimizer.step()  # update wts
```

but I get error when loading the data:

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: hey, can you add more error information (for the line) and maybe update the title bc the error doesnt have to much with your machine-learning problem I think. Anyway, this error occurs when you got an integer value bigger than 2147483647, are your bitstrings really bits or did you convert them to normal strings?

Comment: thanks, 1. what title do you think will be more appropriate? 2. it's realy bitstrings

Comment: maybe try to somehow save/store your bitstrings as a normal string since only the 1 and 0 pattern matters and not in what format it is, maybe then you dont have to try and load to big numbers

Comment: but when loading the data as string 
` tmp_x = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                           usecols=[0], delimiter=",", skiprows=0, dtype=np.str)`
I get the error
`TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.str_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.`

Comment: no I mean when producing the data, produce it as a string and save the string to a text file (but I dont know how you are producing the data so I cant know if its possible for you to do)

Comment: I have the "real" function which represent the laguage so I can create the data as needed.
Do you mean that instead of creating kind of map, I have to create it as sentences?
but I don't have sequences in this language, only words

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228904/discussion-between-user14942713-and-theodor-peifer).